# Using CONCAT in MATCH AGAINST

Tags: php, mysql, match, match-against

I'm having a problem with a search page. 
I have a list of products which I want to search

the search must include:

- product name - produse.produs
- category - categorii.categorie
- variant name - variante.nume_varianta
- variant code - variante.nume_varianta

  ```
                  SELECT 
      produse.*, variante.*, categorii.categorie 
      FROM produse
      LEFT JOIN variante ON variante.id_produs=produse.id_produs
      LEFT JOIN categorii ON categorii.id_categorie=produse.id_categorie
      LEFT JOIN produse_valori ON produse_valori.id_produs=produse.id_produs
      WHERE MATCH (CONCAT_WS( produse.produs, variante.varianta_cod ,categorii.categorie, variante.nume_varianta))  AGAINST ( '.$keyword.' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) and produse.activ=1 
      GROUP BY produse.id_produs
  ```

But no results
I get this error in phpMyAdmin:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

Comment: `'".$keyword."'` isn't SQL.

Comment: Why are you using `CONCAT_WS()` within `MATCH()`??

Comment: @h2ooooooo $keyword is the sintax to search

Comment: @eggyal what do you suggest?

Comment: @nickRO87 It doesn't matter - you say you can't use the SQL in PHPMyAdmin because PHPMyAdmin reads SQL - not PHP code. It doesn't know what `'".$keyword."'` is, because it doesn't touch the PHP compiler. If you run queries in PHPMyAdmin you need to make sure that they're valid **SQL** - not PHP. It's only called "PHPMyAdmin" because it's made in PHP.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I'm testing the code in phpMyAdmin. The code it's in a php file

Comment: @eggyal  The question is: Can i use a concat sintax (like the one i used) in a match against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use a concat sintax (like the one i used) in a match against?

No, you must not use CONCAT_WS() inside MATCH(). Just name the columns.

The arguments to MATCH() must be the columns in a FULLTEXT index. All the columns defined for the index, in the same order as they are defined in the index.

A FULLTEXT index, like any index, can only include columns from *one* table. There are no indexes in MySQL that span multiple tables.

If you want to search multiple tables, you need a FULLTEXT index in *each* table. And you need one MATCH() for each table.

```
SELECT 
produse.*, variante.*, categorii.categorie 
FROM produse
LEFT JOIN variante ON variante.id_produs=produse.id_produs
LEFT JOIN categorii ON categorii.id_categorie=produse.id_categorie
LEFT JOIN produse_valori ON produse_valori.id_produs=produse.id_produs
WHERE
produse.activ=1 
AND (
    MATCH(produse.produs) AGAINST('.$keyword.' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    OR MATCH(variante.varianta_cod, variante.nume_varianta) AGAINST('.$keyword.' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    OR MATCH(categorii.categorie) AGAINST('.$keyword.' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
)
GROUP BY produse.id_produs
```

If you need a fulltext index that spans tables, you'd have to use a different fulltext indexing tool like [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com) or [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/). These tools can index the results of any SELECT query, including queries with joins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can I include relevance if i'm searching like this in more than one field?

Comment: You can get relevance only by using `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`. Why don't you read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)?